# Отображение сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css, ftp

Когда открываю сайт напрямую, то все хорошо работает(скриншот 1), слайдер исправен, аккордеон открывается, НО как только я открываю сайт через ftp, то сразу появляется такая проблема:слайдер пропадает, аккордеон не срабатывает при нажатии, и вообще ничего, что я делал на js не срабатывает.(на скриншоте 2 показано).

Что это такое?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: наверное, по ftp не подтягиваются скрипты.

Answer (score 0):

сайт надо в браузере открывать, что значит через ftp? если просто скачать файл и закинуть его в браузер работать не будет, - для локального тестирования надо webserver ставить и настраивать на нем сайт, только после этого запускать.

Comment: а хотя не, я ошибаюсь, если без php то будет работать. надо все файлы скачать по ftp сперва, там могут быть недостающие скрипты. а еще можно нажать F12 и посмотреть в консоли, какую ошибку браузер показывает.

Comment: Я наверное неправильно выразился,извините. В общем, у меня сайт залит на хостинг. Без php и всего такого. Просто html/css/js. Я пытался открыть этот сайт через телефон свой, просто вводя адрес в браузере и вот получил такую проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Любая отладка начинается с простого.

1. Зайдите в сеть(В панель разработчика в браузере). Убедитесь, что все
       документы необходимые для работы доступны (Скорее всего один из
       компонентов (напр.`jQuery`) не доступен по указанной ссылке);
2. Зайдите в консоль. Убедитесь, что нет ошибок;
3. Запустите через консоль скрипты, какие используются на сайте.
   Например, чтобы проверить доступна ли `jQuery`, просто напишите в
       консоль `jQuery` и нвжмите Enter. И проделайте так с каждой
       необходимой библиотекой. Должно быть любое значение кроме
       `undefined`.